# sign out button not load when using FirebaseUI

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

i try to create sign out button from FirebaseUI, when when i try it wont show sign out button. the idea is if user login, sign out button will came out, but if user not login, button will hide.
when i try, it show me `TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null`, and this is my logout page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.3/firebase.js"></script>
        <script>
            var config = {
                apiKey: "AIzaSyBIi34ndZxxLq2l1gtpzFnAjohPU18pyCk",
                authDomain: "skripsi-adeguntoro.firebaseapp.com",
                databaseURL: "https://skripsi-adeguntoro.firebaseio.com",
                projectId: "skripsi-adeguntoro",
                storageBucket: "skripsi-adeguntoro.appspot.com",
                messagingSenderId: "181721142188"
            };
            firebase.initializeApp(config);
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var out = document.getElementById('signOut');
            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
                if(user){
                    document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>"+user.displayName+"</h1><h2>"+user.email+"</h2>";
                    out.classList.remove('hide');
                    console.log(user);
                    out.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                        firebase.auth().signOut();
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log('user not login');
                    out.classList.add('hide');
                }
            });
        </script>
        <h1>You Done</h1>
        <button type="button" id="signOut" class="btn btn-action hide">Sign out</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: put the javascript code, just after end of your body, ;)

Comment: still hidden, no error in console.

Comment: Yes, your not logged!!!

Comment: i'm logged, check this picture : http://i.imgur.com/O109by7.png

Answer (score 0):

I'm  sure is code order look at this simple [demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/39g64p4v/)

```
<button type="button" id="signOut" class="btn btn-action hide">Sign out</button>
<button type="button" id="showBtn" class="btn btn-action" onclick="showBtn()">show</button>
<script>
function showBtn(e){
 console.log(e);
    var out = document.getElementById('signOut');
  out.classList.remove('hide');
 }
</script>
```

So please re-order your html like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.3/firebase.js"></script>
        <script>
            var config = {
                apiKey: "AIzaSyBIi34ndZxxLq2l1gtpzFnAjohPU18pyCk",
                authDomain: "skripsi-adeguntoro.firebaseapp.com",
                databaseURL: "https://skripsi-adeguntoro.firebaseio.com",
                projectId: "skripsi-adeguntoro",
                storageBucket: "skripsi-adeguntoro.appspot.com",
                messagingSenderId: "181721142188"
            };
            firebase.initializeApp(config);
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
<h1>You Done</h1>
        <button type="button" id="signOut" class="btn btn-action hide">Sign out</button>
        <script>
            var out = document.getElementById('signOut');
            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
                if(user){
                    document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>"+user.displayName+"</h1><h2>"+user.email+"</h2>";
                    out.classList.remove('hide');
                    console.log(user);
                    out.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                        firebase.auth().signOut();
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log('user not login');
                    out.classList.add('hide');
                }
            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

AS you can see i put the html tag before the tag of the script, im sure will be something like this.

Comment: i think i solve it, if i add "document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>"+user.displayName+"</h1><h2>"+user.email+"</h2>;", button will not show up, but if i remove it, button will show up..